# Why do I lose visual styles when I run a form in an AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I load two forms, one the normal way via `Application.Run`, and one via an AppDomain using the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());

    AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("bob", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
    dom.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    Test t = (Test)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Test).FullName);
    t.Run();
}
```

With the following code in `Test`:

```
public class Test : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I don't get any visual styles when `Form2` is displayed. If I call `new Test().Run();` from a button click event in the `Form1` loaded above, the styles are displayed correctly.

Loaded from `Form1`'s button click handler (not in the app domain):

[image]

Loaded via the AppDomain:

[image]

I have looked online but cannot find a reason why visual styles within the window are lost. As you can see, it has a square pre-XP feel to it.

Can anyone advise how to retain the visual styles when loading a control through an AppDomain? Please note that this is just a test and going forwards this will be used for plugins.

Comment: Your code doesn't repro the problem.  Post better code, mention the Windows and .NET version you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.EnableVisualStyles()` applies to an **AppDomain**. If you open your forms from another AppDomain without calling **EnableVisualStyles** in it, those forms won't have the visual styles applied.

Comment: No.  The underlying operating system call is CreateActCtx() to create the activation context.  It doesn't know anything about AppDomains.

Comment: Thank you! :) It's always the little things!